# Android Parcelable as wrapper

Tags: java, android

According to [this](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/), is better to implement Parcelable then Serializable.

However, i had most of my entities already done and to not implement the interface to each one as it seems too much work for all my entities, I decided to create a Parcelable Wrapper like this.
But is really better? Usually I save 1, 2 objects top and it works fine, but this regarded as bad use of Parcelable, or even the same (bad) thing as Serializable?

```
public class SaveParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private HashMap<String, Object> values;

    public SaveParcelable() {
        this.values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getValue(String key) {
        if (this.values.containsKey(key))
            return (T) this.values.get(key);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
        this.values.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds runtime overhead, and it would not appear to save you any coding. You still need to override `writeToParcel()`, implement `CREATOR`, and write a suitable constructor... which is all you need for implementing `Parcelable` in the first place. Yes, perhaps it saves you the `describeContents()`, but that's boilerplate. Since this doesn't help, and it adds overhead, why are you bothering with it?

Comment: It seems there is something off about this. I had no need to implement `writeToParcel()` nor `describeContents()`. I use this class to save my objects as it is in `onSaveInstanceState()` and it works.